# systemctl force order with before

Tags: service, systemctl

I want to create a `systemctl` service that mounts partitions required by `lighttpd`. In the `my-service.service` file, I wrote the following:

```
[Unit]
Before=lighttpd

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/mount_script
Type=notify
User=user
Group=user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I want to enable it, I have the following error printed in `syslog`:

```
systemd[1]: Reloading.
systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/my-service.service:2: Failed to add dependency on lighttpd, ignoring: Invalid argument
```

I don't understand how I can force `lighttpd` to be launched after `my-service`...

From the manual:

```
Before=: The units listed in this directive will not be started
         until the current unit is marked as started if they are
         activated at the same time. This does not imply a dependency
         relationship and must be used in conjunction with one of the
         above directives if this is desired.
```

Comment: you don't put your partition in the /etc/fstab?

Comment: the service does more than that. Actually it's related to the mount of an encrypted folder with custom things to be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the unit is `lighttpd.service`, not just `lighttpd`, so that is what you need to specify.